# Java 8 - How to create Iterable from List<T> and new T without creating temporary variable?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

Is it possible to put `Iterable<? extends Module> modules` without creating temporary variable `ms` and add new element?

```
List<Module> ms = new ArrayList<>(super.superModules);
ms.add(new newModule());
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(super.stage, ms);
```

In parent:

```
protected List<Module> superModules= new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(CucumberModules.createScenarioModule(), new aaaModule(), new bbbModule(), new cccModule()));
```

My called method:

```
public static Injector createInjector(Stage stage, Iterable<? extends Module> modules) {
    return new InternalInjectorCreator().stage(stage).addModules(modules).build();
}
```

Comment: @VGR, no, he would miss `new newModule()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `createInjector` method does not require a `List`, you don’t need to construct a `List`. You can use

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(super.stage, () ->
    Stream.concat(super.superModules.stream(), Stream.of(new NewModule())).iterator());
```

The `Iterable` is a functional interface, as its only abstract method is `iterator()`, which can be fulfilled by a function providing an `Iterator` on demand.

There are 3rd party libraries offering `Iterator` composition, so you could combine `super.superModules.iterator()` with `new NewModule()` as another element. With builtin facilities, we can construct a concatenated stream and convert it to an iterator. This still avoids allocating new storage for a composed collection.

Answer (score 1):

Having a mutable list called 'superModules' sounds like a bad idea; I don't think you'd want any other code to be able to modify this list, no?

**Assuming you have java11+**, you can just write: `protected final List<Module> superModules = List.of(CucumberModules.createScenarioModule(), ...);`

Then, I understand you want to make a new list, containing all the elements from this list + one more element. No, there is no simple one-liner to mix up a list and an element.

There are hacks which I strongly advise you don't use. For example:

```
Stream.of(super.superModules, List.of(new NewModule()).flatMap(List::stream).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

these just serve to obfuscate what you're trying to do. I wouldn't even put the above on a single line for readability purposes.

**Java 8:**

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(super.stage, () ->
                    Stream.concat(super.superModules.stream(), Stream.of(new NewModule()))
                    .iterator());
```

Comment: @sgrillon if you need legacy java answers, you should add it to the question and title that only java 8 stuff will do

Comment: @sgrillon for Java 8, remove the `new ArrayList<>( … )` that wraps the `Arrays.asList(…)` and consider wrapping it in a `Collections.unmodifiableList(…)` instead.

Comment: @rzwitserloot your stream example is not a hack. I’d preferable use `Stream.concat(super.superModules.stream(), Stream.of(new NewModule())) …`, but still, your stream example is neither, wrong nor hackish.

Comment: @Holger That is definitely an unreadable mess. When you see that, you don't instantly think: Oh, okay, this is making a new list out of an existing list + one element. "Readability" is in the eye of the beholder. Maybe it seems that way to you. I don't think a stackoverflow comment is a useful venue to discuss what Joe Q. average coder is gonna see.

Comment: When you think, a piece of code doesn't express its intent, you may put it into a reusable method and give it a meaningful name, e.g `listPlusOneElement`. But regardless of whether you consider it readable or not, using an API the intended way is not a hack.

Answer (score -1):

You can do Arrays.asList(module1, module2, module3)

Comment: no, `Arrays.asList(module1, module2, module3)` is the 1st part but he would miss `new newModule()`